# Sliding window over an image OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to define a window that scans across an image, I want to  find the average RGB values in each window and output them.

I have managed to get the average RGB values for the entire image like this:

```
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg')

mean = cv2.mean(img)

print mean[0]
print mean[1]
print mean[2]
```

Gives:

```
#Output
51.0028081597
63.1069849537
123.663025174
```

How could I apply this mean function to a moving window and output the values for each window?

EDIT:

Here is what I have now:

```
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg')

def new(img):
    rows,cols = img.shape
    final = np.zeros((rows, cols, 3, 3))
    for x in (0,1,2):
        for y in (0,1,2):
            img1 = np.vstack((img[x:],img[:x]))
            img1 = np.column_stack((img1[:,y:],img1[:,:y]))
            final[x::3,y::3] = np.swapaxes(img1.reshape(rows/3,3,cols/3,-1),1,2)
            b,g,r = cv2.split(final)
            rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
            mean = cv2.mean(rgb_img)
            print mean[0]
            print mean[1]
            print mean[2]
```

But now I am getting zero output.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896841/find-a-3x3-sliding-window-over-an-image?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @runDOSrun This does help thanks :) but when I insert my code into the for loop suggested by 'fraxel' I now get no output? Do I need to do something to 'final' to be able to parse it through the cv2.mean() function?

Comment: what about cv2.filter2D with a kernel of 1/9 ?

Comment: @runDOSrun I did use print statements, take a look at the edit to my post above can you see anything blaringly obvious that i've missed?

Comment: not sure how this would help [cv2.filter2D](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#d-convolution-image-filtering)?

Comment: You're not calling your function

Comment: @runDOSrun Im not using any cv methods for the window just to find the mean rgb values. Is there something wrong with the sliding window function I am using? Also when i call my function `mean = cv2.mean(new)` I get `TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar.` If at all possible could you provide an answer to the question. Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a script similar to the given links. It basically divides your img to 3*3 parts and then computes mean (and standard deviation) of each part. With a little array optimization I think you can use it real time/on video.

PS: Divisions should be integer division

EDIT: now the script gives 9 outputs each represent a mean of its own region.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('aerial_me.jpg')
scale=3
y_len,x_len,_=img.shape

mean_values=[]
for y in range(scale):
for x in range(scale):
    cropped_image=img[(y*y_len)/scale:((y+1)*y_len)/scale,
                        (x*x_len)/scale:((x+1)*x_len)/scale]

    mean_val,std_dev=cv2.meanStdDev(cropped_image)
    mean_val=mean_val[:3]

    mean_values.append([mean_val])
mean_values=np.asarray(mean_values)
print mean_values.reshape(3,3,3)
```

The output is bgr mean values of each window:

```
[[[  69.63661573   66.75843063   65.02066449]
  [ 118.39233345  114.72655391  116.14441964]
  [ 159.26887164  143.40760348  144.63208436]]

 [[  75.50831044  107.45708276  103.0781851 ]
  [ 108.46450034  141.52005495  139.84878949]
  [ 122.67583265  154.86071992  153.67907072]]

 [[  83.67678571  131.45284169  128.27706902]
  [  86.57919815  129.09968235  128.64439389]
  [  90.1102402   135.33173999  132.86622807]]]
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Comment: Thaks for the reply :) I don't want to crop the image though, as my next step is to do this on a video sequence and I feel that this will complicate things using your method.

Comment: I edited the answer, please look at it again. I suppose this is what you want to get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I change the amount of regions the image is split into say I wanted 6*6?

Comment: scale parameter is for that purpose. ie if you want to divide 6 by 6, you should change '  scale=6  ' . If you want to print the matrix, use 'mean_values.reshape(3,scale,scale)'

Answer (score 1):

Filter with a kernel of shape equal to your window, and values all equal to 1/window_areas. The result is local average you seek (also known as a "box blur" operation).

Comment: Im NOT trying to blur the image by averaging the pixels and changing the centre pixel value though, I just want to output the average rgb values for each 3x3 window.

Comment: And isn't that the same as making a copy of the original image and blurring it as described? (modulo the usual border issues, for which you'll need to choose your favorite convolution mode)